# Connection to MySql db not possible - "SELECT command denied for user [...]"

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I'm just working at my tool which connects to my rented MySql database. (so much for the theory).
And yes, it works with the following code, but only with localhost. (data are censored)

Following string is placed to class "Common.cs"

```
 // String which is used to connect
   public static string myConnection = @"datasource=****.****.****.com;port=3306;username=****;password=****;"
```

Following code is placed to "frmMain.cs"

```
// The code of the procedure which is used to connect
        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = textUsername.Text;
        string password = textPassword.Text;

        try
        {
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(Common.myConnection);

            MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * from ha_system.main where name='" + username + "' and password='" + password + "' ;", myConn);

            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            myConn.Open();
            myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;

            //myReader loads data
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
            // [...]
            }
      }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
     }
```

So the problem is that it throws me while connecting this exception:
"SELECT command denied to user 'xxxxxx'@'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' for table 'main'"

Same when I try to connect to a db4free.com's database. The data are definately correct and I have the privileges to connect or rather select and so on. (I have already contacted the company to help me out. They say I have all required privileges and they can't do anything for me.)

Note: I can also connect to this db with Navicat or other programs to manage MySql servers.

So what may be the error? Why does it appear and how to fix?
Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the reason, but string concatenation is a bad thing to do. If your username or password variables contains a single quote then the whole command will be invalid. 
And do not forget the problems with Sql Injection.

You could try to change your code in this way

```
string username = textUsername.Text;
string password = textPassword.Text;

try
{
    string cmdText = "SELECT * from ha_system.main where name=@uname AND and password=@pwd";
    using(MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(Common.myConnection))
    using(MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, myConn))
    {
         myConn.Open();
         SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", username);
         SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", password);
         using(MySqlDataReader myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader())
         {
             ....
         }
    }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for trying help me out. It doesn't get better, appears the same error.

Comment: I suggest to look at the permission assigned to your user when it tries to connect from a remote client. The error message contains the `user@host` so it seems that it is a problem when you connect from a remote client. Use an administrative tool that can work over the net and specify `%` for the host from which your user could connect.

Answer (score 0):

By default, all IPs are blocked and must be added to an access list in order to access the server. So, before connecting to MySQL from another computer, the connecting computer must be enabled as an Access Host.

If you do not know your IP address, find it by going [here](https://www.google.com/?q=what%20is%20my%20ip%20address#q=what%20is%20my%20ip%20address).

Also, Having a dynamic IP address means that the connecting IP address can change periodically, depending on the Internet Service Provider (ISP). You must update the connecting IP in Remote MySQL every time it changes.

When Using cPanel X3 Theme

1. Log into cPanel.
2. Under Databases, click the Remote MySQL icon.
3. In the Host field, type in the connecting IP address.
4. Click Add Host.

You should now be able to connect remotely to your database.